# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly in netcoreapp3.1 worker service project

Tags: c#, .net-core, polly

I was trying to implement the following article:
https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory

I'm using HttpFactory in my Worker Service project to get some data, I want to make it more robust using `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`.

The problem is that I keep getting the following error even though the package is installed :

> Error CS0234
> The type or namespace name 'Polly' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SolutionLibrary\SolutionLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

What did I miss ?

Comment: Please do not include the solution into your question. Please leave a separate post for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing that package or assembly name isn't the same as the namespace(s) the code lives in. Although it's often convention that a package named "Foo" will occupy the namespace "Foo" and related namespaces will be something like "Foo.Bar", etc. it's not the only way to do this.

You can find out what namespaces and classes a library makes available to you by using the Object Browser:

1. In Visual Studio, select "View"
2. Select "Object Browser"
3. You will see a list of assemblies that are referenced by your solution
4. Scroll down to "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" and expand it

[image]

5. You can see that it declares code in 4 namespaces:

   - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
   - Microsoft.Extensions.Http
   - Microsoft.Extensions.Internal
   - Polly

Clicking on "PollyHttpClientBuilderExtensions" shows the methods made available  by the class:

[image]

And, as the name suggests, the method signature displayed in the lower pane indicates that the selected method is an extension method on `IHttpClientBuilder`, so you have to use it in conjunction with `services.AddHttpClient()`. It seems likely that this is the one you want to access in your code. Therefore, you should include the following `using`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did some more research after your insight and got it working! Added the working code to the post for future reffrence